# tableau - cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function

Tags: tableau-api

This is the calculated field I'm creating

IIF(ATTR([Segment])=[Parameters].[Segment],
1+SQRT(2)*COS((1-[Result%])*180*PI()/180),1)

and I get the error - "cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function".

I can't work out how to get past this error.

[these are the contents of the fields in the equation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsnEC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter and result need to be aggregated as well. Try:

```
IIF(ATTR([Segment])=ATTR([Parameters].[Segment]), 1+SQRT(2)*COS((1-SUM([Result%]))*180*PI()/180),1)
```

Comment: You’re surely right about needing to aggregate the Result% field, but I don’t think you need to treat a parameter as an attribute